# Play audio chunks instead of full file in javascript & node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio-streaming

I am looking for a solution to play live audio i.e audio in chunks instead of reading the entire file and then start streaming audio. I want the user to select the file which he wants to stream and then it will start streaming to users. I am using `socket.io-stream` package for the same. Below is the code which I am using.

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io-stream/0.9.1/socket.io-stream.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('#file').change(function(e) {
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            var stream = ss.createStream();
            let parts = [];

            var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream(file);
            blobStream.on('data',function(chunk){
                parts.push(chunk);
            })
            blobStream.on('end',function(){
                audio.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(parts));
                audio.play();
            })
            blobStream.pipe(stream);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Don't know why above code is not working for me. Can anyone please help with the same?

Comment: Why use web sockets for this?  You could go one layer down, use regular HTTP, and not have to code anything.  Otherwise you're going to need to use MediaSource Extensions, which limits you to specific container formats.

Comment: Thank you for the response Brad! Can you please provide any example for that?

Comment: It's as simple as `<audio src="https://your-node-server.example/something">` on the client.  Then on your server, just send the stream data as the HTTP response.

Comment: I think you are asking me to directly pass the audio url into the audio tag in frontend. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but I want to work with streaming. Can you please provide me any example if you have.

Comment: That *is* streaming.  If you use an `<audio>` tag, the browser will stream the response from your server.  And on your server, just respond with whatever that stream content should be.  Use whatever chunks you were going to use anyway, but send them in a stream directly.